# New operators inside tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros

I am trying to declare a new operator (only using horizontal and vertical lines and labels). By now I used `tikzpicture` for that with the following code:

```
\newcommand{\newtypeline}[3]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]%
\draw (0,0) -- (10ex,0ex);%
\draw (5ex,-1ex) -- (5ex,1ex);
\node[label=left:{$#1$}] at (0,0 ) {};
\node[label=above:{$#2$}] at (5ex,1ex ) {};
\node[label=below:{$#3$}] at (5ex,-1ex ) {};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
```

Problem is that I'd like to use that new command within another `tikz` environment - and there both `tikz`s environments start interacting with each other. Is there any way of  declaring an operator to later embed into `tikzpicture`s?

Edit:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,arrows,shapes,snakes,topaths,trees,backgrounds}
\newcommand{\newtypeline}[3]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}% 
\draw (0,0) -- (10ex,0ex);% \draw (5ex,-1ex) -- (5ex,1ex); 
\node[label=left:{$#1$}] at (0,0 ) {}; 
\node[label=above:{$#2$}] at (5ex,1ex ) {}; 
\node[label=below:{$#3$}] at (5ex,-1ex ) {}; 
\end{tikzpicture}% 
} 
\begin{document} 
intend to look like: 
\newtypeline{a}{b}{c} looks like: 
\begin{tikzpicture}[->] 
\node at (0,1) {\newtypeline{a}{b}{c}}; 
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. — Nesting TikZ pictures is a tricky business and is best to be avoided.

Comment: Well, I'd be totally happy with a definition of the above operator that avoids the use of tikzpicture at all. I'll post a minimal working example in the next post

Comment: @Dominik code doesn't format in comments: you can edit your question, add the code and indent by four spaces using the `{}` button.

Comment: You can remove the tikzpicture environment and insert the picture via `path picture` inside nodes and standalone otherwise.

Comment: @percusse I'm sorry, but I think I don't completely understand your suggestion - could you give me the respective code? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can define your command *without* TikZ to avoid the dangers and side-effects of nesting `tikzpicture`s; you can do something like:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,arrows,shapes,snakes,topaths,trees,backgrounds}

\newcommand{\newtypeline}[3]{%
\begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}
$#1$
\end{varwidth}~%
\begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}
\centering
\raisebox{0.5ex}{$#2$}\\
\rule[1ex]{10ex}{0.4pt}\\
\raisebox{0ex}{$#3$}
\end{varwidth}% 
} 

\begin{document} 

intend to look like: 
\newtypeline{a}{b}{c} looks like: 
\begin{tikzpicture}[->] 
\node at (0,1) {\newtypeline{a}{b}{c}}; 
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

After a new requirement in a comment:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,arrows,shapes,snakes,topaths,trees,backgrounds}

\newcommand{\newtypeline}[3]{%
\begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}
$#1$
\end{varwidth}~%
\begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}
\centering
\raisebox{0.5ex}{$#2$}\\
\rule[1ex]{10ex}{0.4pt}\rlap{\hspace*{-5ex}\rule{0.4pt}{2ex}}\\
\raisebox{0ex}{$#3$}
\end{varwidth}% 
} 

\begin{document} 

intend to look like: 
\newtypeline{a}{b}{c} looks like: 
\begin{tikzpicture}[->] 
\node at (0,1) {\newtypeline{a}{b}{c}}; 
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hey Gonzalo, thanks for the answer. Unfortunaltey I also wanted a small vertical line in the middle of the horizontal line - which I didn't know how to do with the $\rule$ environment.

Comment: @Dominik please see my updated answer. Next time, please mention all you requirements in the original question.

Comment: Especially for pointing out that a vertical line is nothing but a very shot and very wide horizontal line ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In the end I went for declaring all parameters explicitly to overwrite parameters inherited from the outer tikzpicture layer. In addition with some cropping that did my job. The final definition I used was:

```
\newcommand{\newtypeline}[3]{
\mbox{
\begin{tikzpicture}[-,>=stealth',shorten >=0pt,auto,node distance=0cm,semithick,scale=1]
\clip(-3ex,-2.5ex) rectangle (26.5ex,3.2ex);
\draw (0,0) -- (24ex,0ex);%
\draw (12ex,-0.8ex) -- (12ex,0.8ex);
\node[label={}] at (-2ex,0 ) {$#1$};
\node[label={}] at (12ex,2ex ) {$#2$};
\node[label={}] at (12ex,-2ex ) {$#3$};
\end{tikzpicture}
}}
}
```

Comment: You have several spurious blank spaces.